# spring batch loop calls to Rest API

Tags: spring-batch

I have the Rest API application with endpoint which process the data (tiny operation which sets the status to DB) in a paginated way - with page size and page number - and returns a number of data which needs to be processed (total rows got from DB).

I'd like to use the Spring Batch component in order to trigger the calls in a kind of loop, for example

1. first call to API (with pageSize=x and pageNumber=y)
2. if in response the numer > 0 then trigger next call to API (pageSize=x, pageNumber=y+1) and if response=0 then abort the job

Is such loop is doable in the Spring Batch?
As I'm new to the Batch topic I'm not sure which Batch components is suitable for my usecase (just ItemProcessor for reading responses and WriterProcessor for making a calls?; should I use tasklets or maybe chunks approach?).

Thanks in advance for any input or hints.